# Abrir puerto 8080 escucha en Linux

Tags: linux, puertos

Estoy intentando abrir el puerto 8080 como escucha a través del comando `ufw allow 8080/tcp` y después `ufw reload`  pero al ejecutar `netstat -tulpn`  no me aparece el puerto como escucha, ¿hay que ejecutar algún comandos más?

Comment: Subir un proceso/servicio que escuche por ese puerto

Answer (score 1):

Con ufw solo habilitas el puerto en el firewall; dejas que si llega un mensaje a ese puerto pase.

Pero el `netstat -l` te muestra los puertos para los que algún proceso ha hecho *bind*. Si levantas un servidor web en el 8080, este servidor hace el bind y, a partir de ese momento, los mensajes dirigidos al puerto 8080 llegarán al proceso. Pero en eso el firewall no interviene para nada.

Comment: ¿Y como haría para que esté incluido el puerto 8080 al ejecutar `netstat -l`?

Comment: Levantar un proceso que haga *bind* con ese puerto. Pero parece que estás algo confundido. Un puerto solo es un número, lo que trata el mensaje es el proceso asociado. Si quieres usar el puerto 8080 para un servicio web usarás un proceso que entienda HTTP, pero nada te impide poner otro tipo de servicio. El puerto en sí no es nada y no determina nada.

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo lo que estás haciendo, solo lo habilitas en tu firewall. Creo que esos comandos son de una distro basada en Ubuntu, porque hay otras distros que se debe utilizar el comando `iptables`. Sea como sea, creo que tu solución es posible de la siguiente manera:

### Listar los puertos

Para listar los puertos debes usar el comando `netstat` o `ss` de la siguiente manera:

`netstat -lntu` o `ss -lntu`, esto te mostrará algo como esto:

```
Netid              State               Recv-Q              Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                            Peer Address:Port              
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                      0.0.0.0:68                                   0.0.0.0:*                 
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                      0.0.0.0:45475                                0.0.0.0:*                 
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                      0.0.0.0:631                                  0.0.0.0:*                 
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                  224.0.0.251:5353                                 0.0.0.0:*                 
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                      0.0.0.0:5353                                 0.0.0.0:*                 
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                         [::]:5353                                    [::]:*                 
udp                UNCONN              0                   0                                         [::]:52071                                   [::]:*                 
tcp                LISTEN              0                   5                                    127.0.0.1:631                                  0.0.0.0:*                 
tcp                LISTEN              0                   80                                   127.0.0.1:3306                                 0.0.0.0:*                 
tcp                LISTEN              0                   128                                          *:80                                         *:*                 
tcp                LISTEN              0                   5                                        [::1]:631                                     [::]:*                 
tcp                LISTEN              0                   128                                          *:443                                        *:*
```

### Abriendo un puerto

Luego de haber verificado que tu puerto está realmente libre, tienes que habilitarlo o *"abrirlo"* para que pueda recibir conexiones y eso se logra de nuevo con los comandos `netstat` o `ss`, usándolos de la siguiente manera:

`netstat -na | grep :8080` o `ss -na | grep :8080`

La salida debe quedar en blanco para verificar que no se está usando.

### Añadiendo el Puerto e Iniciando el Servicio

Luego sí haces el `sudo ufw allow 8080` o en su defecto:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

Esto configura el cortafuegos para añadir (-A) la nueva regla para aceptar paquetes de entrada a través del protocolo (-p) TCP donde el puerto de destino (--dport) es 8080, y especifica la regla de destino (-j) como ACCEPT.

Por último haces: `sudo service ufw restart`

Y deberías tener tu puerto añadido para escuchar y con el comando `ls | nc -l -p 8080` puedes testear o simplemente haciendo uso de telnet: `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`.

Recuerda que debes reiniciar el servicio `ufw` o `iptables` luego de cada actualización.

Saludos.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Pero al ejecutar `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080` me aparece: Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused Y sigo sin poder habilitar dicho puerto como escucha